# TypeScript Generic method signature: Adding inline constraints, so that a value is both - in object keynames and a string

Tags: typescript

How to alter the signature (inline) of `sortArrayItemsByDate`, so as to introduce the following additional constraints (cumulatively):

1. `T` should have a key named `propName` (a value is in object key-names)
2. `T[propName]` should be a string (in the same time)

Link to StackBlitz [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-zaggi-typescript-generic-signature-with-return-type)

```
 const sortArrayItemsByDate = <T>(items: T[], propName: string): T[] =>
    items.sort((a: T, b: T) => Date.parse(a[propName]) - Date.parse(b[propName]));


 interface StudentModel {
    name: string;
    birthday: string;
 }

  const s0: StudentModel = {
    name: "Peter",
    birthday: "2001-11-23",
  };

  const s1: StudentModel = {
     name: "John",
     birthday: "2003-11-30",
  };

  const students: StudentModel[] = [s0, s1];
  const studentsSorted = sortArrayItemsByDate(students, 'birthday');
```

Comment: do you require any additional help zaggi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrain `T` to extend `Record<keyof T,string>`
and make `propName`: `keyof T`

```
const sortArrayItemsByDate = <T extends Record<keyof T,string>>(items: T[], propName: keyof T): T[] =>
    items.sort((a: T, b: T) => Date.parse(a[propName]) - Date.parse(b[propName]));
```

Comment: `T extends Record<keyof T, string>>` is probably the constraint you want so as not to require an index signature if `T` is an interface type

Comment: nice, there you are @jcalz! :)

Comment: Simplified answer with feedback